# UnboundLocalError: local variable '...' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, regex, function

I have text in a file that looks like this:

146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554
156.127.178.177 - okuneva5222 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1" 416 14701

I need to parse out the text with regex using the anchor titles. I am not sure why i am getting this error. I have tried moving the return all over the place and no luck.

My code :

'''

```
import re
def logs():
    lst = []
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        pattern = '''
        (?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+) 
        (\ [-]\ )
        (?P<user_name>((?<=- )(\w+\s|[-]\s)))
        (?P<time>([\ \[].+[\]]\ ))
        (?P<request>[\"].+[\"])
        (\ .+)
        '''
        for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
            new = item.groupdict()
            lst1 = lst.append(new)
    return lst1
    
logs()
```

'''

Comment: Looks like the space in `(?<=- )` is meaningful, escape it, i.e. `(?<=-\ )`. Also, replace your `for` with `return [item.groupdict() for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE)]`

Comment: `lst.append()` doesn't return anything, so `lst1 = lst.append(new)` doesn't make much sense. And as you get `UnboundLocalError`, I'd assume that `re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE)` doesn't find anything so `lst1` is never initialized. Try returning `lst` and debug your regex

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the space in `(?<=- )` is meaningful, you need to escape it, i.e. you should use `(?<=-\ )`.

Also, since you get no matches, `lst1` is not initialized and returning `lst1` fails eventually.

You can use

```py
import re
def logs():
    lst = []
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
        pattern = r'''
        (?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) 
        (\ -\ )
        (?P<user_name>((?<=-\ )(\w+\s|-\s)))
        (?P<time>([\ \[].+\]\ ))
        (?P<request>".+")
        (\ .+)
        '''
        return [item.groupdict() for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE)]
    return lst
    
logs()
```

Note you missed a `\` before the last `\d+`, and overused character classes, I removed a couple of `[...]`